# How to assign a belongsTo relation in Laravel without saving to database?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I have the following 2 models:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class Product extends Model
{
    //some other property of the Model

    public function productType() {
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Models\ProductType', 'product_type_id');
    }
    
    public function theComplicatedFunctionBeingTested() {
        //Some calculation with consideration of ProductType
        return $result;
    }
}
```

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class ProductType extends Model
{
    //some other property of the Model
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany( 'App\Models\Product', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Now that I want to write unit test for `theComplicatedFunctionBeingTested()` in the `Product` model. I don't want to mock the model if it is not necessary, so I create real objects of these Model instead in my unit test.

```php
<?php
use Illumniate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase;

use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\ProductType;

class ProductFunctionTest extends TestCase
{
    private $testProduct, $testProductType;

    private function commonDataSetUp() {
        $this->testProductType = new ProductType;
        $this->testProductType->product_type_id = 1;
        $this->testProductType->name = "publication";

        $this->testProduct = new Product;
        $this->testProduct->name = "testing product";
        //I tried to assign a relation like this, but this is not working
        $this->testProduct->productType = $this->testProductType;
    }

    public function testComplicatedProductFunction() {
        $this->commonDataSetUp();
        $result = $this->testProduct->theComplicatedFunctionBeingTested();
        $this->assertEquals( 'my_expected_result', $result);
    }
}
```

However, the relation setup is not successful. As `$this->testProduct->productType` is not set, the default behavior of Laravel code base is to try accessing database, and as no database connection is set for unit test, it throws exception and the test failed.

So, with no database, what should be the correct way to set up the relation?

Comment: So when you are creating an object of the model class the default behavior is to have a db connection ready/set which is why it's advised to mock

Comment: Use an sqlite database for testing. You can't have a relationship without a database.

Comment: Why are you not using [factories](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories)?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Because I don't want to have a database? While it is possible to have a sqlite for this, I don't feel like it is necessary?

Comment: You need it, use sqlite or your production database engine in a docker container, but you need it. I don't have enough time right now on why, but check my SO profile and you will find help about tests with databases...

Comment: had you tried shouldReceive method to mock the behavior of the relation ?

Comment: @KhayamKhan The function to be tested is in the model, so I believe I should not mock it?

Comment: Then you should try creating instances of Product and ProductType without saving to the database by the make method as for as I know.

Comment: Why not just removing the items when the test finishes? I think it is better make database to be involved too. So the test would be more realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Since the relationship is One to Many, you can use

- save() => to add single ProductType, or
- saveMany() => to add more than one ProductType

in your case , try to use save() after calling the relationship

```
    $this->testProductType = new ProductType;
    $this->testProductType->product_type_id = 1;
    $this->testProductType->name = "publication";

    $this->testProduct = new Product;
    $this->testProduct->name = "testing product";
    // You do need to save this first to gain product_id
    $this->testProduct->save(); 
    $this->testProduct->productType()->save($this->testProductType);
```

if you want to add 2 or more ProductType, try like this

```
    $this->testProduct->productType()->saveMany([
       new ProductType(['name' => 'Abc']),
       new ProductType(['name' => 'Def']),
       new ProductType(['name' => 'Ghi']),
    ]);
```

Comment: A database is needed to call `save()`, but there is no database for my case.

Comment: are there any reason that you want to test your code without database ? what do you want to achieve with this test ? can you please explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

The code bellows works properly. So you can use **setRelation**.

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class ProductType extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'product_id');
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function productType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ProductType::class, 'product_type_id');
    }

    public function theComplicatedFunctionBeingTested()
    {
        return $this->productType->name . " " . $this->name;
    }
}

class Test extends TestCase
{
    private $testProduct, $testProductType;

    private function commonDataSetUp()
    {
        $this->testProductType = new ProductType;
        $this->testProductType->product_type_id = 1;
        $this->testProductType->name = "publication";
        $this->testProduct = new Product;
        $this->testProduct->name = "testing product";
        $this->testProduct->setRelation('productType', $this->testProductType);
    }

    public function testComplicatedProductFunction()
    {
        $this->commonDataSetUp();
        $result = $this->testProduct->theComplicatedFunctionBeingTested();
        $this->assertEquals("publication testing product", $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried the `setRelation()` function but it is not working without calling `save()`

Comment: I dont understand. Since the code that I provided worked properly and the test passed. Do you see any error or could you could you provide more code/context?

Comment: The actual code I test the method is different (as it is code in work which I cannot publicly paste here), but basically the code is still trying to search in database when  `$this->productType->name` is called, resulting in an connection error as there is no database setup for test. This means the setRelation is not working property so the model need to search the database for what productType is the product having.

Comment: are you sure that the error is happening on this piece of code.
I runned it in a playground and it works without a database:
https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/46866753-6221-4383-a9d1-f51fac9714b9

Comment: Yes, I am sure it is exactly that line that cause the problem. I have added the line `dd($this->testProduct->productType` right after `$this->commonDataSetUp()` and it tries to access the database. I guess the possible difference is either because I am using Laravel 9, or the playground code is called in route function instead of a UnitTest?

Comment: I put on a route function because I dont know how to run a unit test on the playground but on my machine I called it in a unit test. Not sure about the laravel version but I dont think thats the problem. Can you create a public repository with this problem on github so I can take a look?

Answer (score -3):

You should try this code

```php
$this->testProduct->setRelation("productType", $this->testProductType);
```

`setRelation` is documented in Laravel's API [here](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setRelation)

Comment: That is not the solution, he must use Factories on a test

Comment: I have tried this but it is still not working. I believe `setRelation` would only set the relation after `save()` is called.